# MySQL GUI which is able to display unique values in column filter (like in MS Access)

Tags: mysql, database, filter

i am looking for a DB GUI or a similar siftware (not Excel), where could I manualy and quickly filter in columns and could see uniqu values for a selected column whne other filters are activated. Something like in the pictures. First I have filtered in column "mainP2" value 4 and then when I clicked on colomn "mainP1" I see that only values 1,2,3 are in tat columnn.
I have allready tried some apps but still can not find this feature anywhere.
Thx for help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is Stackoverflow the right place for this question? i don't know.

Comment: Hello BTjacker - StackOverflow is about solving programming (coding) problems. Your question would fit better over at the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @kiltek Definitely not. There's a dedicated close vote reason for it.